# How to Add developer certificate in two machines with single certificate?

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, xcode4.5, ios-provisioning

I have a developer certificate and installed it in my machine. I need to use the same in another mac machine. I have downloaded from the certificate portal and installed the certificate. ( its showing "Valid Signing Identity not Found ). But it is not getting listed under Keys section ( keychainAccess -> keys ).

I found some links in SO but none helps me in my case.

Can some one provide me steps followed to install the certificates in two machines? **I heard from my friend that we need to add a developer under team and add private and public key of the machine, but I dont know how to do it.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to migrate both the private and the public part of the key. What you get from the provisioinig portal is only the public part that Apple generates.

In order to move it to another Mac, open `Keychain Access` on the mac that has the working certificate, right click on it and select `Export <your certificate name>`. Then, on the next screen choose `Personal Information Exchange (.p12)` as the file format and click save. You'll be prompted first for a password that will be used to encode the `.p12` file (you can leave it blank) and then for your keychain password.

You can then open the `.p12` file on the other mac to import the certificate with both the private and public keys.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I ll give a try and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by below steps:

To Crate Certificate:

1) From Keychain: Request certification

2) Upload certificate

3) Download certificate and install in your Mac
Note: This downloaded certification will only installed in Mac from where you have create request certification.

4) Now, go to Keychain, and check your certificate.

5) Export certificate as ".p12" file, give password.

6) Install this ".p12" file in another Mac. Then you will be able to install it.

Hope your problem will resolve.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I ll give a try and get back to you.